# Improve numerous choices in django

Tags: html, django

I'm working with choices in Django. I need to improve a lot of choices (exactly 48), and I want to know if there's a better way to do that, instead of the way that I'm trying to do it, because I think that the way I'm trying is not really optitum and is not visually appealing.

```
nota_35="Acoustic Bass Drum"
nota_36="Bass Drum 1"
nota_37="Side Stick"
nota_38="Acoustic Snare"
nota_39="Hand Clap"

Notas=((nota_35,'Acoustic Bass Drum'),(nota_36,'Bass Drum 1'),(nota_37,'Side Stick'),(nota_38,'Acoustic Snare'),(nota_39,'Hand Clap'))
notas=models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=Notas)
```

This is an example. The real problem has, as I said 48 options, and each choice has his own option.

Comment: And? 48 it's not a big sequence choices, you write one time and will be using all time this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using PostgreSQL as your DB Backend (you can find this in settings.py), then you can use [ArrayField or JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/) to store enumerated data:

```
from django.db import models
from djando.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class Notas(models.Model):
  values = ArrayField()
```

and then something like

```
notas = Notas(values=[])
notas.values[39] = "Hand Clap"
```